# Div set to 100% height won't grow when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side div menu that is set to height: 100%. It works fine until the page expands and i need to scroll and then the div stays at the original height. I tried:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $menu.css({'bottom':'0px'});
});
```

As well as:

```
$menu.css({'height':'100px'});
```

Neither had any affect. The css for the div is

```
.menu_click{
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
display: none;
position: absolute;
font-size: 16px;
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2;

}
```

In short I want the div to grow as needed, even if the page scrolls. The page starts with no scroll and certain elements grow, so it causes there to be a scroll.

Comment: Do you mean you want it `position: fixed`? If it's absolute, and the nearest positioned element is `body`, then it'll pan out of view when you scroll - is that what's happening?

Comment: Ohhh my god such an easy fix. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

`height: 100%` can be temperamental because 100% of the height of the document can be less than the height of the window depending on the content/CSS structure (unlike `width`, where 100% will translate to both).

The simplest way to handle this would probably be to just copy the window height:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $menu.css( 'height', $(window).height() );
});
```

Comment: So that doesn't seem to be working if there is a scroll bar. It sets the window height fine, the the body is longer then the window because of the scroll. Could I do some sort of body height?

Comment: So position fixed was the solution. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting the height of the div to `100vh` in your css? This will set the div to 100% of the viewport height and will respond appropriately to the changing size of the window.

Comment: That's what I tried, but the scrollable area is larger than the window/viewport so it still leaves space at the bottom.

Comment: So position fixed was the solution. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So position fixed was the solution. This stops the div from moving when I scroll.

Comment: @chazsolo should post this answer and you should select it as the correct answer.